No carga las imagenes
tengo un problema con una web creada con un theme de astro al momento de hacer el despliegue en netlify no aparecen las imagenes salen con icono roto me podrian ayudar con una explicacion para poder ender a que se debe este problema.

sin ver nada es dificil decirte cual es el problema... el problema es que tu sitio no encuentra las imagenes...

ese es el repo de la web recien estoy empezado en este mundo lo desplegue en netlify pero las imagenes no se muestran https://github.com/andrests32/Web-Tentacion.git

El codigo debe estar en la pregunta... esperas que alguien recorra todo tu repo para ver que encuentra???

Te recomiendo incluir un [mcve] en tu pregunta.
